# Is it possible to add a customized property for jQuery event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Sample code is as following:

```
$('a').mousedown(function(event)
   {
            event.ABC = true;

   });

$(window).mousedown(function(event)
    {
        console.log("event.ABC:",event.ABC);
         //outputs "undefined "

        if( event.ABC)
        {
          // do sth
        } 
        else
        {
            //let it go  
        }


    });
```

Comment: So clicking an `<a>` element will make clicking the window not doing anything anymore? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, I'm guessing it would be a lot easier if you didn't have to mess with the events object.  Just set up a flag variable when your `<a>`'s are clicked:

```
var eventABC = false;

$('a').mousedown(function() {
        eventABC = true;
});

$(window).mousedown(function() {
    console.log("eventABC:", eventABC);
    //outputs true if <a> clicked, false otherwise

    if(eventABC) {
      // do sth
    } else {
        //let it go  
    }

    eventABC = false;
});
```

But you can trigger events in jQuery.  Like so:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(window).trigger("eventABC", ['CustomProperty1', 'CustomProperty2']);
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('eventABC', function(event, param1, param2) {
    alert("eventABC triggered: " + param1);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Others have mentioned that the jQuery event gets recreated for each callback, which is why any attribute you add to the jQuery event is lost.

However, the jQuery event has an `originalEvent` attribute which **does** persist through the entire event propagation phase.

Instead of `event.ABC`, you can just do `event.originalEvent.ABC`.

Note: If you intend on using this extensively, you may want to add a myAppData attribute to store all your data in, i.e. `event.originalEvent.myAppData.ABC`. This makes it easy to identify which event attributes are your custom ones and also reduces the possibility of name collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having with your example is the event object is created fresh for each callback, it's not a global object that gets passed around to every event callback function.

Your best bet is probably to create your own EventArgs object at whichever scope level is appropriate, and add all the properties to it that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The output is undefined, because whenever the event is triggered then new event object is created. You just modified some different event object. And unfortunetly there is no way to do this except for rewriting jQuery. ;) Try using some other (global) variables/objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional data to the event object.

```
$('a').bind('mousedown',{ABC:true},function(event)
  alert(event.data.ABC);
});
```

However that data will only be available inside that event handler, not the one bound to the window.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("*").mousedown(function(e){
e.ABC = "abcdef";
}); //place this code first
```

and then you can use it like that

`$("yourSelector").mousedown(function(e){
alert(e.ABC); // >> abcdef
});`

[exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/v8mfn38f/)